# VS2013 Windows Phone 8 Emulator cannot connect to internet

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation, visual-studio-2013, hyper-v

I am running a simple ootb new Windows Phone 8.0 application in the emulator for Visual Studio 2013.  I am using a Surface Pro, 1st generation, core i5, 4 GB RAM.  Hyper V is installed, with no other virtualizing systems (like VirtualBox).  Connecting via wireless.

When I run the emulator and am prompted, "Do you want to configure the emulator to connect to the Internet?", if I select "Yes", I get the following error message:

```
The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to create the external network switches:
Something happened while creating a switch:
Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.
Ethernet port '{...}' - bind failed: {Out of Paper} The printer is out of paper. (0x8000000E).
```

I have tried running through solutions suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/91aed6f7-fc1e-4739-b38e-7ee39811d095/hyperv-fails-to-add-virtual-switch-with-printer-out-of-paper-error?forum=w8itprovirt) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/670e5e57-aa1e-4ddf-8701-d38204ca569c/hyperv-windows-8-error-applying-virtual-switch-properties-changes-wireless-network?forum=winserverhyperv#af01ecfb-153b-40d4-ab4d-035f9b960ca6), but unsuccessfully.

Any further ideas as to what can be done?

Comment: Well, have you tried feeding paper into your emulator? (Sorry I can't help, but I lost it when I saw the error message.)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a virtual switch in hyper-v called " Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch"? This was not created for me when I ran into your situation. If you create a new one manually with that exact name, and set to internal, it should work. I found the solution on a blo[enter link description here](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2012/11/01/troubleshooting-windows-phone-8-emulator-problems.aspx)g.